# junit parameterized test does not output result in sequence

Tags: java, junit, parameterized

I am using junit to test a constructor with different parameters. The code runs fine. But the output result is in random sequence.

```
public class Meetup {
public Meetup(int N) {
    if(N <= 0) { throw  new IllegalArgumentException();}
    System.out.println("Meetup is created !");
}
```

}

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MeetupTest {
    private int N;
    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static List<Object[]> data(){
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {0},{1},{2},{-3},{4},{-5}
        });
    }    
    public MeetupTest(int N) {
        this.N = N;//break point
    }    
    @Test
    public void testMeetup(){
        System.out.println("parameter: " + N);
        new Meetup(N);
    }
}
```

If I run the MeetupTest, I got the following result (random sequence):

```
parameter: 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
parameter: 4
Meetup is created !
parameter: -5
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
parameter: 1
Meetup is created !
parameter: 2
Meetup is created !
parameter: -3
```

This is the result which I expect. But I have to run the code in debug mode (set break point at this.N = N).

```
parameter: 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
parameter: 1
Meetup is created !
parameter: 2
Meetup is created !
parameter: -3
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
parameter: 4
Meetup is created !
parameter: -5
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

How to solve this issue? Thanks !

Comment: Why is this a problem for you? The successful execution of tests should not depend on their execution order.

Comment: I expected parameter and exception (or result) are shown in pair. I didn't know " the order of input should mot  matter". Thanks for your comment !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not an issue.

**Parameterized testing is about testing exactly the same functionality with multiple inputs.** Those should be independent and **the order should not matter.**